# Use data from array as variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, svg

If got an array with some names of vars i use in my project.

```
var frau = ['frau1', 'frau2', 'frau3', 'frau4', 'frau5'];
```

I want to loop through die array an use the data of the array for an snap.svg function:

```
function noneopacityFrau(){
  for (index = 0; index < frau.length; ++index) {
    frau[index].attr({opacity: '0'});
  }
}
```

I try to let it work like this:

```
function noneopacityFrau(){ 
  frau1.attr({opacity: '0'});
  frau2.attr({opacity: '0'});
  frau3.attr({opacity: '0'});
  frau4.attr({opacity: '0'});
  frau5.attr({opacity: '0'});
}
```

Comment: `attr()` is function defined on jQuery. `frau[index]` is **string**. You must be getting error.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve??

Comment: frau[index] is not an element so you definitely cannot do what you are trying but if that is an element id then you may do something like document.getElementById(frau[index]).attr(). Beside syntax for attribute is incorrect

Comment: at least add the markup..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now im assuming this uses jquery but not sure so here goes if the elements in the array are the names of the classes:

```
function noneopacityFrau(){
  for (index = 0; index < frau.length; ++index) {
    $("."+frau[index]).attr({opacity: '0'});
  }
}
```

If the elements of the arrays are id's:

```
 function noneopacityFrau(){
      for (index = 0; index < frau.length; ++index) {
        $("#"+frau[index]).attr({opacity: '0'});
      }
    }
```

There is a good chance that im wrong please dont consider this answer if it is.  :/